# How to make HTTPS SOAP request bypassing SSL certificate in .Net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, https, soap-client, web-reference

I had a problem trying to reach HTTPS web reference service in c# .Net project.

I got this message when i trying to send request to web service.

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Then i found solution check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this code to my web service class constructor.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (mender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

It solves the problem.